# How to pass multiple file names from input type file to a web method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

Hi ihave this input with type file with multiple select enabled.
i need to get the files from the file input and pass it to my webmethod but i'm getting none in my webmethod, i've read that `prop` return a list, i have this code in jquery

```
function post_RepAttach(){
var params = {
Ocap_no:$('#txtOcapNo').val(),
file_Name:$('#FileUpload1').prop("files")[0]
}
var files = $('#FileUpload1').prop("files")[0];
alert(files);
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: baseUrl + 'Create-OCAP.aspx/post_attachment_rep',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var response = data;

            if (typeof callback != 'undefined') {
                //hideLoadingGif();
                //callback(response);
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            //hideLoadingGif();
            console.log(xhr, status, error);
        }
    });
}
```

i have try this `$('#FileUpload1').prop("files")` remove the `[0]` but still no luck
and here's my webMethod

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static string post_attachment_rep(string Ocap_no, List<string> file_Name)
        {
            OcapDataAccess ODA = new OcapDataAccess();
            bool result;

            result = ODA.insert_reports(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/OCAP/files/Reports/" + file_Name.ToString()), Ocap_no);
            if (result == true)
            {
                return "1";
            }
            else
            {
                return "0";
            }

        }
```

but the `file_Name` count is zero even if i selected files
how can i achive it.
Hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Can you give us more detail about `FileUpload1`? Where did you read that `i've read that prop return a list,`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileNames = $.map( $('#FileUpload1').prop("files"), function(val) { return val.name; });
```

and params is :

```
    var params = {
    Ocap_no:$('#txtOcapNo').val(),
    file_Name:fileNames }
 }
```